# How can I access the Django server using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)?

Tags: python, django, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 and installed django within a python virtual environment. I'm able to start the django server successfully, but when I type in "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" in my windows 10 browser I don't get a response.

I've tried changing the port number to something else (eg. python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:7171) and I still get nothing.

I don't think it's a firewall issue, as WSL and the browser and all running on the same Windows 10 laptop. Do you know what the issue might be?

```
(env) $ python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 26, 2018 - 00:50:25
Django version 2.0.7, using settings 'portfolio.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Windows Version: Windows 10 build 1709 (16299.492)

Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Comment: Does it work on Linux, e.g. `curl 127.0.0.1:8000`?

Answer (score 2):

On your WSL terminal run:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Include your hostname as Allowed Host(Computer Name) in *settings.py*.

In your browser run: `http://yourhostname:8080`.

Answer (score 0):

When doing this myself a while back, I found there was no way to bind things running in WSL to localhost.

I did however have success when connecting via my hostname.

So, given the hostname GAMMAFLYER, do the following:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This allows external connections.

Then in your browser:

```
http://GAMMAFLYER:8000
```

Comment: Weird, [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1131874/how-to-access-localhost-of-linux-subsystem-from-windows) suggests otherwise. Out of curiosity, what do you get when you ping `GAMMAFLYER`?

Comment: This was a problem at some point, but if they fixed it in the last few months then It seems that my knowledge of the WSL system is outdated.

Comment: Thanks Shadow. I tried with the hostname, but it's still not getting a response. When I don't use WSL, and just run django with python on windows, it works just fine. I think I'm going to have to switch back. And I was just getting excited about WSL

Comment: Yeah, I too am rather hyped about it. It's a shame it's not there yet - but the fact it's as far along as it is gives me hope.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and answer of @Shadow works for me well, i.e. I have ability to access http://HOSTNAME:8000 from windows after `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` on WSL.

But there is a way to get it work usual way and access `http://localhost:8000` on windows by disabling a VirtualBox network adapter for those who have VirtualBox installed on their Windows systems.

I have found that the IP address of my hostname on windows is the IP of `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter`:

(windows cmd):

`ping -4 HOSTNAME`

```
Pinging HOSTNAME [192.168.56.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

`ipconfig -all`

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : ***
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7d75:46fe:41d8:1ee3%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : ***
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : ***
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

After I have disabled this adapter from `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` and reran `python manage.py runserver` on WSL shell it worked well and I have ability to access http://localhost:8000 from windows.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running wsl2 on a windows 10 box. I ran into this issue when trying to setup a django project. I was able to get it working by running the following command, on powershell.

```
netsh interface portproxy reset
```

There were some config errors with my proxyport and the above command was able to fix those errors. So if you had wsl2 working at one point and now it's not working, run that command. However, **if you just installed wsl2 then you need to add a proxy port in order to access the port locally**:
`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=4000 connectaddress=192.168.101.100`

In this case I am exposing the **4000** port.

**Source:**

- https://dev.to/vishnumohanrk/wsl-port-forwarding-2e22
- [Netsh interface portproxy commands Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions